# Seeing "referencedColumnNames(ID) ... not mapped to a single property" error with a 1-M relationship after adding a composite key to the "1" side

Tags: jpa, key, composite

I have an existing JPA entity ("Reference") with an ID column as its primary key that it inherits from a base class "BaseEntity" (using the @MappedSuperclass annotation on the superclass).

I also have a 1-M relationship between a Reference and another entity called Violation. Violation was previously defined with a foreign key "REFERENCE_ID" to the "ID" column of the Reference entity.

Recently, I tried to add an unrelated composite key to the Reference entity. This should not have affected the 1-M relationship between Reference and Violation. However, when I run the code in my tomcat server, I see the following stack trace:

Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: referencedColumnNames(ID) of org.qcri.copydetection.sdk.metastore.entity.Violation.reference referencing org.qcri.copydetection.sdk.metastore.entity.Reference not mapped to a single property
        at org.hibernate.cfg.BinderHelper.createSyntheticPropertyReference(BinderHelper.java:205) ~[hibernate-annotations-3.5.6-Final.jar:3.5.6-Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:110) ~[hibernate-annotations-3.5.6-Final.jar:3.5.6-Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.processEndOfQueue(AnnotationConfiguration.java:541) ~[hibernate-annotations-3.5.6-Final.jar:3.5.6-Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.processFkSecondPassInOrder(AnnotationConfiguration.java:523) ~[hibernate-annotations-3.5.6-Final.jar:3.5.6-Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.java:380) ~[hibernate-annotations-3.5.6-Final.jar:3.5.6-Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1206) ~[hibernate-core-3.5.6-Final.jar:3.5.6-Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildMappings(Ejb3Configuration.java:1459) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.5.6-Final.jar:3.5.6-Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.EventListenerConfigurator.configure(EventListenerConfigurator.java:193) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.5.6-Final.jar:3.5.6-Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:1086) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.5.6-Final.jar:3.5.6-Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:685) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.5.6-Final.jar:3.5.6-Final]
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-3.5.6-Final.jar:3.5.6-Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:268) ~[spring-orm-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310) ~[spring-orm-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514) ~[spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452) ~[spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
        ... 39 common frames omitted

Here is the code for the 3 classes involved:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "REFERENCE")
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
@IdClass(Reference.ContextualName.class)
public class Reference extends BaseEntity {

@Column(name= "LOCATION", unique=true)
@XmlElement
private String location;

@Id
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name = "name", column = @Column(name = "NAME")),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "account", column = @Column(name = "ACCOUNT_ID"))
})

@Column(name = "NAME")
@XmlElement
private String name;

@ManyToOne(optional=false)
@XmlTransient
@JoinColumn(name = "ACCOUNT_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
private Account account;


public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}

public Reference() {}

public Reference(String name) {
    setName(name);
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public Account getAccount() {
    return this.account;
}

public void setAccount(Account account) {
    this.account = account;
}

@Embeddable
private class ContextualName implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3687389984589209378L;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "NAME")
    @XmlElement
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    @XmlTransient
    @JoinColumn(name = "ACCOUNT_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    private Account account;

    ContextualName() {}
}
}

@MappedSuperclass
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public abstract class BaseEntity {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "ID")
@XmlElement
private Long id;

@Basic(optional = true)
@Column(name = "CREATED", insertable = false, updatable = false, columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@XmlElement
private Date creationDate;

protected BaseEntity() {}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    if(this.id==null) {
        this.id = id;
    } else if (this.id!=id) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot change the id after it has been set, as it is a generated field.");
    }
}

public Date getCreationDate() {
    return creationDate;
}

public void setCreationDate(Date creationDate) {
    if(this.creationDate==null) {
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    } else if (this.creationDate!=creationDate) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot change the creation-date after it has been set, as it is a generated field.");
    }
}
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "VIOLATION")
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Violation extends BaseEntity {

@ManyToOne (optional=false, fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "REFERENCE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
private Reference reference;

@ManyToOne (optional=false, fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "SUSPECT_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
private Suspect suspect;

@ManyToOne (optional=false, fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
@XmlTransient
@JoinColumn(name = "SEARCH_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
private Search search;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "SCORE")
@XmlElement
private double score;

public Violation() {}

public Violation(Search search, Reference ref, Suspect sus, double score) {
    this.search = search;
    this.reference = ref;
    this.suspect = sus;
    this.score = score;
}

public double getScore() {
    return score;
}

public void setScore(double score) {
    this.score = score;
}

public Reference getReference() {
    return reference;
}

public void setReference(Reference reference) {
    this.reference = reference;
}

public Suspect getSuspect() {
    return suspect;
}

public void setSuspect(Suspect suspect) {
    this.suspect = suspect;
}

public Search getSearch() {
    return search;
}

public void setSearch(Search search) {
    if(this.search!=null && this.search!=search) {
        this.search.removeViolation(this);
    }
    this.search = search;
    if(search!=null) {
        if(!search.getViolations().contains(this)) {
            search.addViolation(this);
        }
    }
}
}
```

To cut a long story short, I'm totally confused how to go about adding a composite key to an existing (legacy) entity that already has an ID column. I can't remove the ID column, nor can I change the 1-M relationship between Reference and Violation. I can't for the life of me understand the error message because the "REFERENCE_ID" foreign key column of the Violation entity is being mapped to a single "ID" column of the Reference entity.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Since your Reference entity is extending BaseEntity that already has a Primary key defined and it uses generation, why bother having JPA use a composite pk when the ID will uniquely identify Reference anyway?  There doesn't seem much value in using name in a composite pk for Reference, and JPA will hace problems since it hashes on the primary key - so foreign keys using only "ID" will not be allowed if you make the key a composite.

Comment: Actually my goal is to enforce a uniqueness on the Reference entity based on a combination of 2 fields:
- NAME, and
- ACCOUNT_ID.
In other words, two Reference entities associated with the same account cannot both have the same name. Similarly, two Reference entities with the same name can exist if they exist in different accounts. I wanted the db to enforce this sort of uniqueness, instead of doing it at the application level. I figured using a composite pk of this type was the way to fix this. Perhaps there is another way to define uniqueness constraints in JPA independent of pks?

Comment: Would anyone have any suggestions? :) Thanks!